# Can not search mail on Exchange IMAP server by javamail api?

Tags: search, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I can not search mail on Exchange(2013) IMAP server by Javamail API.
I have done a tcpdump found that javamailAPI send the command:
`"A5 SEARCH TO xxx@eyou.net all "`,exchange server return nothing.

I sent a command:
`"A5 SEARCH HEADER TO xxx@eyou.net all"`. then exchange server  return all the matching message。
What can I do ？
thanks verymuch

Comment: sorry for my poor englist

Comment: [Microsoft blogs](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dkhrebin/2013/10/04/how-exchange-imap-search-in-message-header/)   I found the pages

Answer (score 0):

Ya, Exchange is broken.  You can use [HeaderTerm](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/search/HeaderTerm.html) instead.